# Find the Coordinates of Points in a Sine Curve

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The question is as follows:

> The graphs of $y = \sin x$ and $y = k$ (dotted) are shown at right. Given that the coordinates of P are $(θ, k)$, find the coordinates of $Q$, $R$, and $S$, in terms of $θ$ and $k$.

[image]

I know that $\sin\theta = \sin(180-\theta)$. I am thinking that the $x$-coordinate of $R$ would be $180-\theta$ and the $y$-coordinate would just remain the same ($k$). However, I do not know what the $x$-coordinates of $Q$ and $S$ would be. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is in degrees, then $Q$ is $(180-\theta,k)$, $R$ is $(360+\theta,k)$ and $S$ is $(540-\theta,k)$. The period of the sine function is $360$ degrees, so $\sin x= \sin(x+360)$.

If $x$ is in radians, then $Q=(\pi-\theta,k), R=(2\pi+\theta,k), S=(3\pi-\theta,k)$.

Comment: on a graph, $x$ is more likely to be in radians, i suggest you change or augment your answer, but +1 anyway

Comment: @gt6989b Since the OP refers to $180-\theta$, it seems like $\theta$ is in degrees, but I'll edit my answer